# Java exec() issue

Tags: java, ssh, runtime.exec

I'm trying to make Java run the following comand:

```
sshpass -p '[PASSWORD]' ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no [USERNAME]@[HOSTNAME] 'sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $IP --dport [PORT] -j ACCEPT'
```

Only if I run it with the same user which runs Java will it work, I think the problem is in the `exec()` function.

Here is the code that runs the command:

```
if (Config.ENABLE_DDOS_PROTECTION_SYSTEM)
{
    String deny_comms = Config.DDOS_COMMAND_BLOCK;
    deny_comms = deny_comms.replace("$IP", addhost);

    try
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(deny_comms);
        if (Config.ENABLE_DEBUG_DDOS_PROTECTION_SYSTEM)
        {
            LOGGER.info("Accepted IP access GS by " + addhost);
            LOGGER.info("Command is" + deny_comms);
        }

    }
    catch (final IOException e1)
    {
        LOGGER.info("Accepts by ip " + addhost + " no allowed");
        LOGGER.info("Command is" + deny_comms);
    }

}
```

I have tried with all methods execpt the ssh library, anyone can help me please?

Comment: Java has libraries for running SSH clients; consider using those instead

Comment: I'm not expert of java :( there is maybe a solution without adding libraries? if not can you please provide me an example?

Comment: It would really help if you also posted the failure mode.

Comment: Dolda2000 i have not error log... i don't know how to set it up...

Comment: @ewwewewewe: Then it seems that should be your first task. :)

Comment: Using Runtime.exec is bad practice, you should consider using a ProcessBuilder

Comment: @Dolda2000 about java yes... i'm going to be crazy i'm working on this making test for about 7 days, for this reason i wrote on SO

Comment: @Aaron searching in the net i found about ProcessBuilder like a solution but i don't know how to use it, can you please make an example of my case?

Comment: @ewwewewewe: Nevertheless, without knowing why it fails, of course it's going to be hard to debug it, for you or for anyone else.

Comment: When  working with system commands I preffere to use apache commons exec http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/ which is very comfortable.

Comment: Anyone can help me convert this to ProcessBuilder? Showing me an example please?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the use of JSCH a library for handling ssh connections and executions. You can find an example of opening a connection and running a sudo command at: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html

Comment: thank you for answering, like I said before I'm new about java so I know what is the lib you have said but I dont know how to include it, can you please write a complete function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would process with a `ProcessBuilder` :

```
String sshPassword = [...];
String sshCommand = [...];
ProcessBuilder denyCommsBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sshpass",
                                                         "-p", sshPassword,
                                                         sshCommand);
Process denyCommsProc = denyCommsBuilder.start();
denyCommsProc.waitFor();
```

The `ProcessBuilder` constructor can take an array or List of Strings and will distinguish their first element as the executed command and the next ones as its arguments.
Use `start()` to spawn a new `Process`, which you will have to `waitFor()` if you want to have the same blocking execution as in `Runtime.exec()`.

If you execute a lot of these ssh commands with `sshpass`, you could create your own wrapper extending `ProcessBuilder` :

```
public class RemoteExecutionBuilder extends ProcessBuilder {

    public RemoteExecutionBuilder(String remoteHost, String remotePassword, String remoteCommand, String... sshOptions) {
        super("sshpass", "-p", remotePassword, "ssh " + sshOptions.join(" ") + " " + remoteHost + " -- " + remoteCommand);
    }
}
```

Well, String concatenation isn't efficient, but I hope you see what I mean.

Comment: you are a genius this is helping me a lot, but in the processBuilder you wrote only: ProcessBuilder denyCommsBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sshpass",
                                                         "-p", sshPassword,
                                                         sshCommand); why list of comands are separated?

Comment: It's not a list of commands but rather a command and its arguments, put together into a String[] or List<String>.

Comment: It may be confusing here since your sshpass command, which is the only command from Java's point of view, actually contains 3 commands : sshpass contains an ssh command as an argument, which itself contains a shell command to execute remotely as an argument

Comment: every your answer i'm understanding better, because i'm coming from php and i understand java a little more of newbies, i'm sorry if i'm asking so much but can you help me making complete java lines that solves my problem? because i don't understand some words in your lines like super, sshOptions.join etc

Comment: I saw your edit and I think your command is fine. The `RemoteExecutionBuilder` class I displayed is based on the assumption you will always execute a command with this format : `sshpass -p <password> ssh <ssh flags> <ssh host> <remote command>`. If it is the case, it may be worth to extend `ProcessBuilder` so that providing <password>, <ssh flags>, <ssh host> and <remote command> is enough to start a new process